# Table Layout and Table Row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I need to create six textview dynamically in but one condition each table row have only three  textview for mine i need to place two table row and place three textview each please

Comment: I will give answer but one condition you need to do it first.

Comment: When did SO became order placement site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
    TableLayout myTable=new TableLayout(this);        
    TextView[][] myTextView=new TextView[3][3];
    myTable.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    TableRow[] myRow=new TableRow[3];        
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        myRow[i]=new TableRow(this);
        myRow[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));           
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {               
            myTextView[i][j]=new TextView(this);  
            myTextView[i][j].setText("Your Text");
            myRow[i].addView(myTextView[i][j]);
        }   
        myTable.addView(myRow[i]);
    }
    LinearLayout lin=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linLayout);
    lin.addView(myTable);
```